# multilingual nodes architecture issue

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Is it possible that node translations aren't new nodes? For example if I translate `/node/1` I get `/node/2` and this is problematic in some cases (comments are not shared between #1 and #2, and entity references are not reused).

Detailed walkthrough:

I'm using `locale`, `translation`, `variable` and `i18n`. I've got 2 languages configured: `EN`, `FR`. I have content types `News` and `Event`. Both have Multilingual support: "Enabled, with translations". The `News` has fields:

- title
- body
- reference to a `Event` (implemented with `entityreference`)

I create 2 node instances:

- /node/1 (#1) Event (EN)
- /node/2 (#2) News (EN) with reference back to #1

I edit #1 and add a translation (FR) and #3 is created. I then translate #2 and #4 is created. The problem is that I have to respecify that the reference from #4 is #3 and not #1. If I use the "Synchronize translations" feature of the content type the workflow is a bit better but still not exactly what I want since on the FR front end when viewing #4 the reference to #1 will be displayed in EN and not FR.

Is there any way to have translations not creating new nodes but instead just translating some fields only?

Also, is the module `i18n` the "defacto standard" for implementing multilingual sites in Drual 7? Or is there something better out there?

Comment: Did you try [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) ? I find it very much easier and efficient than i18n (which is needed for some other parts of the site anyway).

Comment: Have a look on this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17466/node-translation-vs-entity-field-translation

Comment: Done. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) ?

I find it very much easier and efficient than i18n (which is needed for some other parts of the site anyway).

There you get exactly what you're looking for : translations stored in one node only.