# Multisite with i18n module enabled

Tags: i18n-l10n

We have to build a multi lingual site(English and Spanish). There are 2 approaches to enable multi lingual site

1. Single site with i18n module

   - Content,Functionality and layout are almost same for both languages
2. Multi site (Parent English Site and Spanish sub site separate)

   - Content,Functionality and layout are mostly different for Spanish site
   - Parallel Enhancement needs to be done for both languages
   - English language site needs to be redesigned without affection Spanish language site

We are preferring to choose the second approach to build the multilingual site. Please feel free to recommend the Implementation approach using i18n module.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Drupal 7's new multilingual systems compilation](http://hojtsy.hu/multilingual-drupal7). There's even a full book about that matter: [Drupal 7 Multilingual Sites](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-multilingual-sites/book).

When using a single Drupal instance to create a multilingual site, there are two different approaches: **Content Translation** and **Entity Translation** (Read: [Node translation vs. Entity (field) translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17466/node-translation-vs-entity-field-translation)). You may want a multi-site setup (With [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) or without it), especially if you require independent content to appear (not only translations). And the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) suite of modules is a must, it provides the following modules:

- Path Translation
- String Translation
- Taxonomy Translation
- Block Translation
- Variable Translation