# How to translate a node without creating a new node?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have translation enabled for the node type `page`, settings " Require language (Do not allow Language Neutral)." and " Normal - All enabled languages will be allowed".

However, when I'm creating and translating a node, it creates a new node instead of translating just the fields and storing the content in `$node->body["en_US"][0]`. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way in which the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module works, when you go to translate a node the module create a copy in another language, if you want one node with the fields transalted you must look at the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

You can read more in this in [Node translation vs. Entity (field) translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/17466/28275)

Comment: Finally, "entity_translation" was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Skynet a pleasure help you ;-)